# How long before the Sun has given off enough energy=mass for a one meter thick Dyson Sphere at earths orbit?

Tags: nuclear-physics, astrophysics, thermal-radiation, mass-energy, sun

Just for fun: As energy can be converted into mass - what if we had some kind of magic technology which can convert photons into carbon atoms with 100% efficiency. I realize its not as easy as just equating the sun's solar output to the mass of the "membrane" via E=m*C^2? or is it? Maybe there is more energy in an atom than just its mass, what about the electric field generated by the protons for example?

Edit 02/10/2022:

Did a bit more research: Growing a membrane around the sun just by intercepting radiation energy from the sun in all directions and converting it back into mass has a massive (pun intended) problem, even just in theory:

According to the standard model radiation (photons) can only turn into mass=fermions in equal ratios of matter and anti-matter, via "Pair Production":

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matter_creation

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two-photon_physics

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pair_production

So we would need twice the radiation to generate the extra antimatter and we would have to move this antimatter away from our sphere and react it with matter somewhere else to get rid of it.

It occurs to me that, in principle, we could send the anti-matter back into the sun, where it annihilates into exactly the amount of extra radiation we needed to start with....What's wrong with this idea?

This leads to an interesting question/thought experiment about matter transport at light speed using radiation:

(1) Turn the matter into radiation energy via fusion.
(2) Radiate the energy to a different place at light speed.
(3) At that different place turn that radiation into equal parts of matter and anti-matter via pair-production.
(4) Send the anti-matter back to the original location, at sub-relativistic speeds.

What's the problem with this idea?

Thinking about this a bit more and remembering that the laws of physics are independent of the direction of time: If we can turn matter into radiation via fusion, the laws of physics should allow a "reverse fusion" process which turns radiation into matter (no anti-matter required) - how would such a process look like in detail?

Comment: Hi Stefan. Welcome to Phys.SE. Did you try to do a back-of-an-envelope-calculation?

Comment: @Stefan Compare the mass of a 1m thick diamond Dyson sphere with radius equal to the Earth’s orbit with the mass of the Sun. The result may surprise you.

Comment: The Sun converts mass to energy, and you are converting it back. So the Dyson sphere can't have more mass than the Sun, even if the Sun is 100% efficient at conversion (It is far less than 100%). So can you calculate the mass of your Dyson sphere and look up the mass of the Sun?

Comment: ok. Did the back of the envelop calculation, a Dyson Sphere, as specified, made from diamond, with a density of 3.5 g/cm^3, would have about half the mass of Jupiter or 0.05 % of the Sun's mass. Assuming 1.353*10^17 kg sun-weight-loss per year due to radiation, it would take 7 billion years to have enough mass for the diamond Dyson Sphere. But only about 24 years to grow a carbon nanosheet at the distance of planet Mercury. Yearly sun-weight-loss taken from here: http://solar-center.stanford.edu/FAQ/Qshrink.html

Comment: For starters, energy is equivalent to mass but one can not make stable matter "just like that" from a supply of energy. There are very serious thermodynamic limits to that process which make it a hopeless proposition... unless you can start a brand new universe, that is.

Comment: That's extremely interesting. Can you elaborate a little about what you mean by "serious thermodynamic limits" and how the start of a new universe would help? Does it have to do with entropy having to be reduced ? Also with regards to the idea of "reverse fusion" ? Does the second law somehow imply that matter has lower entropy than radiation?  Do you have any links which explain these issues?